# Is it possible to detect if the Invisible Recaptcha was shown to a user?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

In my web page, I validate a form based on Invisible Recaptcha, by calling the calling the function `grecaptcha.execute()`. Usually this happens invisible to the user; all they see is the form submit that is triggered after `grecaptcha` is done verifying.

Sometimes, the not-so-Invisible Recaptcha behaviour is triggered (e.g. if the user behaves suspiciously) and a regular captcha is shown to the user that they must solve. When this happens, I want to detect it programmatically.

**Is it possible to programmatically discover if a captcha was shown to the user after the call to `grecaptcha.execute()`?**

---

So far, I've experimented with watching the DOM using `MutationEvents` and `MutationObservers`. Unfortunately everything interesting is happening inside an `iframe` and it seems to be impossible to tell if the full captcha was shown or not.

I don't want to measure how long it takes for `grecaptcha` to call the callback I give it, because that would be unreliable (e.g. slow mobile connections would skew the results).

---

Markup:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/form">
    Name: (required) <input id="name" name="name">
    <div id="g-recaptcha-div"
        class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="keeeey"
        data-callback="onRecaptchaDone"
        data-size="invisible"></div>
    <button id="thebutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Code:

```
function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.reset();
    grecaptcha.execute();
}
function onRecaptchaDone(token) {
    form.submit();
}
window.onload = function() {
    form.onsubmit = onSubmit;
}
```

Comment: How you are using recaptcha, do you have a callback for recaptcha on submit? How you rendering it?

Comment: Yes sorry - I do have a callback. It gets called with the token provided by the recaptcha API. But it gets called every time in the same way, regardless of whether the captcha was shown.

Comment: Can you show your code here? Initializing of the recaptcha? I mean, are you using `grecaptcha.render(...)`?

Comment: I've added it to the question. I'm using the invisible API, so no call to `render`.

Comment: Where is you `grecaptcha.execute()` being executed, in form submit method or what?

Comment: Robert Steward, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @SujanAdiga no, I didn't. I guess it is intentionally hard or impossible to prevent us from gaming the system.